# Disable the control alt delete prompt to logon to Windows

Tags: windows, login

By default a domain joined machine will ask you to enter Control-Alt-Delete before you can select a user with which to logon to the machine.

This isn't necessary and can be an inconvenience (although it does present a more secure screen from which to start logon). How do you disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enter Start -> Run
2. Type **netplwiz**
3. Select the **Advanced** tab
4. Under **Secure logon**, uncheck "Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete"
5. Click **OK**

Optionally, you can define this via a GPO

disable the policy: Disable CTRL+ALT+DEL requirement for logon

Comment: is netplqiz a part of windows?  When I try that I get an error that Windows cannot find netplqiz

Comment: that was a typo, it should have said netplwiz

Comment: It doesn't work on my XP machine. It does on my Windows Server 2008 machine. I assume this either only works on vista type OS's or server OS's?

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd mention that it's trivial to steal a user's password with a look-alike login screen if you disable ctrl+alt+delete.

Only disable it if all the people with access to the computer are trustworthy (or everyone logs off when they leave every time with no exceptions).

Comment: "Only disable it when..." even if your employees are trustworthy, you can still have this same problem with viruses, etc.

Comment: True, but I wouldn't expect people to require ctrl+alt+del in their own home or something, fellow employees targeting you are more dangerous than viruses targeting everyone.